# orgmode- assign tags via helm/avy?

Tags: org-mode

i have a bunch of tags i define via:

```
(:startgroup)
("Where?")
(:grouptags)
 ("@home" . ?h)
 ("@work" . ?w)
 ("@pc" . ?p)
 ("@family" . ?f)
 ("@shop" . ?s)
 (:endgroup)
 (:startgrouptag)
("people")
(:grouptags)
("allan" . ?a)
("bob" . ?o)
("joel" . ?j)
("david" . ?d)
("boris" . ?b)
("massimo" . ?s)
(:endgrouptag)
```

anyone know of a way to quick add tags via a helm/avy interface?

right now its quite cumbersome to press C-c then C-c to see a list of all tags. also some tags have the same key (?a) and then its impossible to select the 2nd one

Z